# Coldfusion getting data from a second datasource

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion

I have a query which gets data from a second datasource. It is very SLOW. Is there a more effective way to do this?

I think the part that is slow is the ListQualify. It results in a list that contains 40,000 values. However I'm not sure of another way to do it.

```
<cfif GetExtractionData.recordcount gt 0 >

            <cfquery name="queryVPOCar" datasource="Web_Applications">
                Select [strStockNumber] as "STOCK",
                        field1 as "field_1",
                        field2 as "field_2",
                        field3 as "field_3",
                        field4 as "field_4",
                        field5 as "field_5",
                        field6 as "field_6"
                From ExtractionAggregates
                WHERE [strStockNumber] IN (#ListQualify(StockList,"'",",","ALL")# )
            </cfquery>

        <!--- Select an empty Row --->
        <cfquery name="joinQuery" dbtype="query" >
            SELECT *
            FROM queryVPOCar
            WHERE queryVPOCar.STOCK = ''
        </cfquery>

        <!--- Add empty row to table, so we have column names  ---> 
        <cfset QueryAddRow(joinQuery) />

        <!--- if results exist, add them to the query --->
        <cfif queryVPOCar.recordcount gt 1 >
            <cfquery name="GetExtractionData" dbtype="query">

                SELECT * FROM 
                GetExtractionData, queryVPOCar
                WHERE GetExtractionData.STOCK = queryVPOCar.STOCK

                UNION 

                SELECT GetExtractionData.*, joinQuery.*
                FROM GetExtractionData, joinQuery
                WHERE GetExtractionData.STOCK  NOT IN (#ListQualify(ValueList(queryVPOCar.STOCK),"'",",","ALL")# ) 

                ORDER BY STOCK 
            </cfquery>
        </cfif>

    </cfif>
```

Comment: What database engines are in play?

Comment: The first query comes from oracle. The second data comes from Microsoft sql (2010, I think)

Comment: How many records could be in queryVPOCar?  Cause if your DB connections aren't setup to pool connections, and you have a lot of results in it, you could be connecting and disconnecting from the DB a lot.  That tends to be the most expensive (time wise) part of a query, assuming its written half decently.  :)

Comment: I'm looking at about 40,000 records from the original query, there could be that many or less.

Comment: The original query only takes a couple seconds. I'm almost positive my problem here is the STOCK NOT IN ListQualify

Comment: An `IN (...)` clause with that many items could definitely slow things down. I am surprised your db even allowed 40,000 items. Most databases I have used have a much smaller limit. Anyway, replacing the `IN (...)` with a `JOIN` should speed things up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A better way to do this is to use sql server for as much of the database work as possible.  Step 1 will be to install a [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx) to your oracle db on your sql server.  Step 2 is to write a stored procedure that:

- Uses [openquery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx) to get the data from oracle and puts that data into a
  temp table of your sql server database.
- Gets the data from your sql server database tables joining to the temp table

Step 3 is to call the stored procedure from ColdFusion and display the results.

Comment: Linked server? I've never even heard of that, but it sounds promising. Will that have any impact on the oracle server? We use a third party program that runs on that server and uses the oracle db.

Comment: The only impact it will have on the oracle server will be the queries you are running.  However, you are running those anyway.

Comment: Very good thinking +1 @PatrickSchomburg (Dan is innovative for sure)